# Como indexar contenido dinamico en busquedas de google

Tags: seo

Bueno estoy haciendo una pagina tipo diccionario, la pagina tiene un cuadro de busqueda donde el usuario ingresara una palabra y se le enviara a una pagina con el resultado, pero esa pagina al principio estara en blanco y se ira cambiando el contenido segun la busqueda que realize el usuario, supongamos que lanze mi pagina web como haria que el contenido dinamico aparezca en las busquedas de google. Disculpen mi ignorancia en el tema pero soy nuevo en programacion web
Que me aparezca mas omenos asi:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esa duda porque al principio la pagina estara en blanco y el contenido ira cambiando segun la busqueda que realize cada persona.
Este es mi codigo de la pagina principal:

```html
<form action="busqueda.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="buscar" value placeholder="Buscar"/>
   
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="buscar"></input>
  
</form>
```

y este es el codigo de la pagina de busqueda:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<?php
 $db_host="localhost";
 $db_nombre="diccionario";
 $db_usuario="root";
 $db_contra="";
 $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra,$db_nombre);
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
  $busqueda=$_GET["buscar"];
$palabra;
$definicion;
 $consulta="select * from significados where palabra='$busqueda'";
   $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
 while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
 $palabra=$fila["palabra"];
 $definicion=$fila["definicion"];       
 }
 ?>
<body>
 <div>
  <?php echo $palabra;
 ?>
 </div>
 <div>
  <?php echo $definicion;       

 ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo pondría información general en la página que tú dices que aparecerá en blanco. Para fines de SEO no es bueno tener una página en blanco. Es más, esa página hay que cuidarla bien, sería como la página de aterrizaje de tu sitio y el robot de Google la va a rastrear e indexar con esta dirección: `https://buscar.de`, a menos que tú le digas que no la rastree así (lo cual no sería una buena idea). En cuanto a los términos de búsqueda, no podría decirte cómo lo hace, pero lo cierto es que también el robot de Google va a rastrear e indexar los términos de búsqueda...

Comment: ... yo tengo algo parecido en mi sitio. Una página de acogida, y luego, si alguien pone a la url esto al final: `/1` busca el registro una base de datos con ese `id` y muestra la información en la página. El robot de Google se ha encargado de indexar muchas de las páginas, con los diferentes números de identificación al final. No sé si lo hace en base a lo que los usuarios de la página abren, el hecho es que están casi todas las páginas indexadas, puedes verlo haciendo esta búsqueda en Google: `site:deiverbum.org padres`